# Problema con uso de Count

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos

Estoy ocupando el `COUNT` para una consulta a mi bd y mostrármela en mi gráfico, en este caso seria un tipo de sentencia así:

> Contar las filas de la columna 'id_estado' que tengan valor '1', tenga el 'rut' = $rut (que es el que esta logeado) de la tabla 'asistencia'

No sé si se entiende, pero tengo este error envio imagen y código.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CODIGO CONTROLLER

```js
    public function index()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $rutAutenticacion = $user->rut;

        $asistenciaGrafic = DB::table('asistencia')->groupBy('id_estado',1)
        ->where ('rut',$rutAutenticacion)
        ->count();
        return view('Asistencia.index')->with([ "asistenciaGrafic" =>     $asistenciaGrafic]);
    }
```

Espero me puedan ayudar. ¡Gracias!

Comment: 1) los errores también puedes compartirlos como texto; en mi celular es bien difícil ver la imagen de un escritorio. 2) después de pelear y hacer zoom y adivinar, parece que tienes `GROUP BY '1'` y te está diciendo que '1' no es una columna. ¿Cuál es la intención al agrupar por la columna de nombre '1'?

Comment: Esta sintaxis `groupBy('id_estado',1)` esta mal, cuando haces uso de `groupBy()` el segundo argumento que es opcional, debe indicar el ordenamiento, tanto si eliges `ASC` o `DESC`, desconozco que tratabas de hacer con ese 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al parecer estas llamando en la función groupBy() a una columna que no existe '1'.

Yo creo que lo que necesitas es agrear en el where el filtro id_estado = 1 para que de esta forma con COUNT() contara solo las filas de la columna 'id_estado' que tengan valor '1'.

```
public function index()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $rutAutenticacion = $user->rut;

        $asistenciaGrafic = DB::table('asistencia')
        ->where ('rut',$rutAutenticacion)
        ->where ('id_estado', '=', 1)
        ->count();
        return view('Asistencia.index')->with([ "asistenciaGrafic" =>     $asistenciaGrafic]);
    }
```

Saludos

Comment: Esta igualación `where ('id_estado', '=', 1)` también puede quedar así: `where ('id_estado', 1)`

Comment: esta muy bien, gracias pro explicarme un amigo me recomendó hacerlo así, aunque tampoco tenia sentido, ademas desconocía que se podían ocupar 2 'where' en esa sintaxis, muchas gracias por su ayuda!